# RAID config for write heavy postgresql 9.2 database with four disks

Tags: raid, postgresql, hardware-raid

I have a server with 32GB ram, one intel E3-1245 and four 15k SAS disks with a BB LSI MegaRaid controller. I wan't the optimal performance for my server, which will be pretty write heavy at times, and acceptable with less optimization for redundancy, as my data is not very crucial and I will be running a streaming replication along side.

Now what would be best to go with:

1. 3 disks in RAID 0 containing PGDATA + 1 containing SYSTEM and WAL
2. All four in RAID 10 containing both PGDATA, SYSTEM AND WAL
3. 2 disks in RAID 1 containing PGDATA + 2 disks in RAID 1 containing SYSTEM and WAL
4. Something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RAID 10 is definitely the best answer. With four drives there is really nothing else to remotely consider.

http://www.smbitjournal.com/2012/11/one-big-raid-10-a-new-standard-in-server-storage/

http://www.smbitjournal.com/2012/11/choosing-a-raid-level-by-drive-count/

Those two links will address RAID 10 for your scenario from both the use case and the drive count perspective.

Answer (score 2):

RAID-10 is a typical choice for databases.

And you don't have to tinker at separate system drive, unless you have plans to use it heavily (all of the sudden).